# is it possible to open external swf in new flash player with AS3 or AS2?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

is it possible to open external swf in new flash player with AS3 or AS2? I've been searching everywhere for this, but most of what i found is that it's loading into new browser tab not other flash player.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function to execute a new Flash Player.

If you think in this way: Flash Player is an executable in visitor's computer. If you can launch Flash Player, you can launch any executable you want. This causes security problem.

Therefore, you can't launch a new Flash Player.

Comment: But there is a function call fscommand ( exec ) which can execute exe file, but what i'm looking for is to open new swf in other flash player, any clues? @shivan

Answer (score 0):

fscommand(exec) only works with Windows Projector(exe) File, not SWF.

Comment: So, How about opening a directory from the project with AS2/AS3 ?

Comment: I made an Interactive CD in Flash.
Exported it to Windows Projector File (Exe) from Publish settings.

It had list of Clients and when you click on each client's logo it would open the directory from the CD.

i used getURL("foldername/"); for that purpose. if this is what you're asking