# Opening external exe file via fscommand

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have problem opening external `exe` file by clicking a button in `Flash projector`. I have seen that the external file must be under the folder `fscommand`. And this is the code;

```
private function Fnc(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    fscommand("exec", ".\\fscommand\\externalfile.exe");
    trace("***button pressed***");
}
```

However I found that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14993937/3965441) and now I am not sure I can open a flash exe by another flash exe.

*Addition:*
I can succesfully open other `exe`s like Windows Media Player. So the answer might be the case but I don't know.

Comment: Do you have to use Flash Projector? Is very limited in comparison to AIR.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I have to use Flash Projector. AIR might be the last resort.

Comment: In AIR calling external exe would be very easy, in Flash Projector there's always a security sandbox issue possible. Flash Projector have limited rights to user computers and files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why a flash projector can not open another one !! Of course it can, it's just an exe like any other exe file !

You have just a little mistake in the path of the opened exe, so you should write :

```
private function Fnc(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // flash knows that the exe is in the fscommand dir
    fscommand("exec", "externalfile.exe");
    trace("***button pressed***");
}
```

Take a look on this very simple example :

[image]

Hope that can help.

Comment: I didn't get it at all. But it works, probably wrong syntax of giving folder path. Thanks anyways.